# syntax error rails render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a great deal of trouble tracking down a syntax error that rails keeps telling me is in my code but for the life of me I cannot see it!
I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

at the line `render :action => "modal", :layout => false`

and whatever I do I cant get rid of it! Please help me!

```
def new

    @appointment = Appointment.new
    @appointment.patient = current_patient
    @appointment.practice = current_practice


    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:layout] == 'modal'
        render :action => "modal", :layout => false
      else
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @appointment }
      end
    end
end
```

[image: screen shot of better errrors stacktrace]

Comment: Can you please provide a copy of the stack trace ?

Comment: I assume you mean `if params[:layout] == 'modal'` not `=`.

Comment: mbratch yes sorry makes no difference

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois i included a screenshot sorry its the best I can do its hard to copy a stacktrace from better errors #irony

Comment: Can you post the corresponding view? I think you misunderstand your error. I think the error is in your view template and not in the controller action..

Comment: @Mattherick THAKYOU!! I thought I had already checked the view but when I went and looked there was an spare '<%end%>' hanging arround. I wonder why it didnt give me a template syntax error  .... strange. If you ammend your answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** view error:

I think you have to check out your view code. I think you misunderstand your error. I think the error is in your view template and not in the controller action. In your screenshot at the top of the image the following sentence shows you the place of your error: "SyntaxError at app/views/appointments/new".

The controller wants to render the view - in the view is the error - and that´s it :).

btw: possible controller refactoring:

```
def new
  @appointment = Appointment.new
  @appointment.patient = current_patient
  @appointment.practice = current_practice
  render :action => "modal", :layout => (params[:layout] == "modal" ? false : true)
end
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, had already tried it like this and it hadn't worked. But for the sake of it I copied and pasted in your line and I am still getting the same error

Comment: I updated my answer..maybe you do not get the error with the refactored solution.

Comment: thanks for the refactor but unfortunately  am still getting exactly the same error. Originally I thought I was missing something obvious but this is really difficult to track down